# Запустить программу и передать ей параметр

Tags: c#

Мне нужно своей программой запустить другую программу и передать ей параметр.

Делаю я это таким образом:

```
 Process.Start("путь к программе", "параметр(в моем случае я хочу передать строку например E:\Downloads");
```

Но вместо этого программа передает строку "путь где лежит exe моей программы"+ "E:\Downloads"

Comment: Ну или как еще можно сделать, используя C#, тоже самое что делает  bat файл с таким содержанием :

"путь к программе которую надо запустить" -"E:\Downloads\123.txt"

Comment: А почему вы считаете, что передаётся неправильно? Что делает ваша другая программа? Думаю, проблема в ней.

Comment: ну дело в том, что если использовать bat файл, таких проблем не возникает. Вторая программа должна получать параметр который я хочу ей передать и вывести его textBox.

Comment: Но тем не менее. Bat-файл — не аргумент. Приведите релевантную часть кода второй программы.

Comment: Спасибо что отозвались, но я уже нашел ошибку

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нашел ошибку! Не внимательный я, прошу прощения. Ошибся с синтаксисом.
Нужно было так:

```
Process.Start("путь к программе", "/E:\Downloads");
```

Просто нужно было добавить правый слэш в строке с параметром.

Comment: Наверняка вам ещё нужно `"/E:\\Downloads"` (ну или `@"/E:\Downloads"`).